# Why are Android event callbacks unicast based?

Tags: java, android, events, event-handling, observer-pattern

Within the Java space, event handling is usually done though interface dispatch implementing the multicast observer pattern. However, on Android, many interfaces are defined as if there is ever only one subscriber. For instance, the [SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) defines setOnSeekBarChangeListener(..) rather than addOnSeekBarChangeListener(..).

For various reasons, this can be quite limiting and also introduce bugs if different parts of a composite calls setOnSeekBarChangeListener(..), where the latter call removes a previous subscriber... silently!

Why is it implemented this way on Android? When subclassing an existing widget, am I simply expected to roll my own event handling and NOT touch the existing externally exposed one?

Comment: "Silently" Not really. These semantics are included in the method name: set (should) always mean "change the value to something new".

Comment: you always can extend it, and make your own implementation. You are not limited

Comment: I say silently, because if component B (a subclass of component A) itself makes use of the callback and a user of component B expects to be able to use it for his own component C, then component B will break - there is no way for component C to tell that the callback is "taken" and no way for a developer of component B to limit the exposure. I guess it's a good example why composition should be favored over inheritance, but I still don't understand why the unicast limitation exists in the first place.